# Explain parameters in Oracle actual execution plan

Tags: oracle, sql-execution-plan

I am reading Oracle actual execution plan but I don't know about some parameters shown in exported plan:
[Actual execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTlR3.png)

Can someone explain to me about Starts, Buffers, OMem, 1Mem and Used-Mem? Thanks for any explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Starts is the number of times that operation actually happened
- Buffers refers to the amount of buffer read/write (IO) performed
- OMem is the memory estimate needed to perform the operation in memory only. You can consider it as the optimal execution.
- 1Mem is the memory estimate needed to perform the operation in a single pass (R/W from disk or temp disk). Called one-pass execution (i.e. 1Mem)
- Used-Mem is the ACTUAL amount of memory used for the operation.

Sources:

- https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/oracle/execution-plans-part-11-actuals/
- https://gerardnico.com/db/oracle/buffer
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84012/what-are-the-omem-and-1mem-columns-in-the-plan-output

Comment: Please let me know if this answered the question, and if it did, please mark as answer @harry

Comment: Thanks so much for your concise answers. It helps me a lot :)

Comment: No problem @Harry

Comment: Can I ask one more things about Buffers. It's only the buffers that read/write on disk (Physical IO) or it includes logical IO @Jerry M. ?

Comment: It includes logical IO as well @Harry